# undefined method `shift' for "[97, 98, 257, 256]"

Tags: ruby

```
def uncompress(to_uncompress)
  dictionary = (0..255).to_a.map { |element| element.chr }
  output = Array.new
  current = to_uncompress.shift
  output << current
  to_uncompress.each_char do |index|
    previous = current
    current = index
    if current < dictionary.length
      s = dictionary[current]
      output << s
      dictionary << dictionary[previous] + s[0]
    else
      s = dictionary[previous]
      output << s
      dictionary << s
    end
  end
  output.shift
  output
end
```

[97, 98, 257, 256] is the compressed array and when am calling the uncompress method it throws undefined method `shift' for "[97, 98, 257, 256]":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: `[97, 98, 257, 256]` is an array, yes. You, however, have `"[97, 98, 257, 256]"`, which is a completely different matter.

Comment: You left out the only line of code that is actually relevant: the line where you call `uncompress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're given a string literal like that it could be JSON data, or at least it's something the JSON parser can handle:

```
to_uncompress = JSON.parse(to_uncompress)
```

Now it's a proper Array. You may need `require 'json'` at the top of your file to get the JSON module to load.

Comment: @Aditya If you can confirm it's working, mark it as accepted so other people will know it's a good solution. Helps to share.